# Implement Table and Sum replacements scoped with Module

Tags: scoping

Functions like `Table` and `Sum` are scoped with `Block`, rather than `Module`.

For some particular applications, however, one might want to wrap these functions with `Module` to have lexical scoping of the iteration variables.

Is there a simple way to define new functions, let's call them `Table2` and `Sum2`, that would do this automatically?
That would save one from having to manually wrap `Table` and `Sum` inside `Module` all the time.

Comment: Can you show sample code where you need these new functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a reasonably simple way to do it.

I could not use `Module` directly, so I ended up reimplementing the lexical scoping by replacing the iteration variable with some variables generated by `Unique`.

Here is the code for an equivalent of `Sum`:

```
SetAttributes[Sum2, HoldAll]
Sum2[expr_, vars__] := Module[{repl},
  repl = (#[[1]] -> Unique[]) & /@ 
    ReleaseHold[MapAt[HoldPattern, Hold[{vars}], {1, All, 1}]];
  Sum[Unevaluated[expr] /. repl, Evaluate[Unevaluated[vars] /. repl]]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption:**

What OP wants to achieve is an alternate version of `Sum` where the symbols that are replaced by the summation index are only those that appear explicitly and not those that might appear inside the definition of the summand function.

In other words, they want a function that does this:

```
f[x_] := a x;

Sum2[f[a],{a,1,3}]
(*6a*)
```

as opposed to this

```
Sum[f[a],{a,1,3}]
(*14*)
```

**Possible solution:**

This can be achieved with [`Inactivate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html). It is similar to the more familiar `Hold` but it's transparent to the replacement done by `Sum`. Therefore this solution will do the job

```
SetAttributes[mySum2, HoldAll]
mySum2[expr_, vars__] := Activate[Sum[Inactivate[expr], vars]]
```

### Differences with the other answer

**Setting malicious UpValues**

`Inactivate` doesn't stop standard evaluation, but rather it wraps all heads with the symbol `Inactive` so that there are no downvalues that apply. This means that clearly one could break my solution by doing

```
f /: Inactive[f] := 0&;
mySum2[f[a],{a,1,3}]
(*0*)
```

**Order of evaluation**

An important difference is the order of evaluation. The other answer does the same as `Sum`: expands the downvalues chain first, and then adds up the result. My answer instead adds everything up and then applies the rules.

In order to see this in practice we can put a [`Throw`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Throw.html) statement in the sum. The builtin `Sum` and also `Sum2` will [`Catch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catch.html) it immediately while mine won't:

```
g[x_] := Throw[1] x;

Catch[Sum[g[a], {a, 1, 300000}]] // Timing
Catch[Sum2[g[a], {a, 1, 300000}]] // Timing
Catch[mySum[g[a], {a, 1, 300000}]] // Timing
(*
{0.000108,1}
{0.000115,1}
{0.546646,1}
*)
```

For a similar reason my sum is also significantly slower for infinite sums like `Sum[x^n,{n,0,\[Infinity]}]`

**Performance for multiple sums**

On the other hand, for multiple sums the logic in `Sum2` is quite time consuming and my implementation is about a factor of 10 faster

```
With[{vars = Sequence @@ Table[{Unique[], 2}, 20]}, Sum[1, vars]] // Timing
With[{vars = Sequence @@ Table[{Unique[], 2}, 20]}, Sum2[1, vars]] // Timing
With[{vars = Sequence @@ Table[{Unique[], 2}, 20]}, mySum2[1, vars]] // Timing
(*
{0.035266, 1048576}
{14.9894, 1048576}
{1.03961, 1048576}
*)
```

**OwnValues vs DownValues**

Unfortunately `Inactive` does not screen against [`OwnValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html), but only [`DownValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html). This means that we have this counterintuitive behaviour

```
g[] := a;
Sum[g[], {a, 1, 3}]
Sum2[g[], {a, 1, 3}]
mySum2[g[], {a, 1, 3}]
(*
6
3a
3a
*)
```

```
h := a;
Sum[h, {a, 1, 3}]
Sum2[h, {a, 1, 3}]
mySum2[h, {a, 1, 3}]
(*
6
3a
6
*)
```

Note that assigning an `OwnValue` to `a` instead does not give any problems because the summation variables are always held.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @MannyC. As you mentioned, it's unfortunate that it does not screen against `OwnValues`, but I really like its simplicity!